# String formatting error with operators in python

Tags: python, string, formatting

Using Python string formatting, my expected output is:

```
If you took 19 and 13 and added them, you would get 22
```

However not quite sure if I have done it properly. I keep getting this error:

```
 Not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Could you help please?

Code:

```
my_age = 19
teenager = 13

print "If you took %s and %s and added them, then you will get %" %(my_age,teenager,my_age + teenager)
```

Comment: You're missing a specifier after last `%`. You need: `"get %d"`

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing the last 's' after the last % in string

```
print "If you took %s and %s and added them, then you will get %s" %(my_age,teenager,my_age + teenager)
```

Comment: @TKA If you get the answer you wanted, don't forget to click the check mark. If the answer is helpful but not quite right, it is polite to honor the  OP with a thumbs up.